# Compare "Firstname Lastname" with "F. Lastname" in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1` consists of a column (`FullName`) of names in the format `'FirstName LastName'` and a unique identifier (`Key`). `Table2` has a column (`Name`) consisting of these names but in the form `'F. LastName'`.

I would like to replace the Names in `Table2` with the unique identifier (`Key`) from `Table1`. This requires a comparison of the strings in `FullName` and `Name` (this comparison is bijective).

Is this possible to do using SQL?

Comment: Which SQL implementation? Basically, there is crap data in there now that has be normalized before comparing - and the (easiest) way to do this depends on SQL version/vendor.

Comment: sqlite3. I'm interfacing with Python so can always do the normalising crap in there but wld be easier if there was a way using SQL

Comment: I would just use (a one-off) Python script to convert/normalize the data. Do it once and be done with it, hopefully leaving the data in a better state :> You may be able to get somewhere with [instr and substr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) (perhaps using derived relations as an intermediate). YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the update directly, but you have problems code can't overcome.

```
create table table1 (
  key integer primary key,
  firstname varchar(20), 
  lastname varchar(20)
);
insert into "table1" values(1,'Ian','McCormick');
insert into "table1" values(2,'Irving','McCormick');

create table table2 (name varchar(30));
insert into table2 values('I. McCormick');
```

See the problem? Both 'Ian McCormick' and 'Irving McCormick' map to 'I. McCormick'. Which ID number should 'I. McCormick' end up with? There's no way to tell.

Anyway, update carefully. Back up your database. Then add a new column for the id number.

```
alter table Table2
add column key integer;
```

Now you can update the new column without risking the data in the old column.

```
update table2
set key = (select key
          from table1 
          where name = substr(FirstName, 1, 1) || '. ' || LastName);
```

---

You can join on expressions, too. Joining on the expression you intend to use in an update is a good first step--it can alert you to problems before it's too late. Also, as below, it can show you the carnage that can result from bad data.

```
sqlite> select * from table1
   ...> inner join table2 
   ...> on substr(FirstName, 1, 1) || '. ' || LastName = table2.name;

key  firstname  lastname   name          key
--
1    Ian        McCormick  I. McCormick  1
2    Irving     McCormick  I. McCormick  1
```

Notice the mismatch in keys on the second row.

Comment: Perhaps this statement by the OP covers the issue you are talking about here: `this comparison is bijective`. As I take it, their meaning is that there can be no duplicates when transforming a `Firstname Lastname` to the `F. Lastname` form. One other thing is that they do not have two columns (`FirstName` and `LastName`) but only one (`FullName`) for the name.

Comment: In the absence of a constraint enforced by the dbms, "this comparison is bijective" might express a requirement or a hope. Historically, it doesn't represent a reality. you're right about "Fullname"; I'll rewrite that query later, time permitting. (The existing query shows the tactic, though, and the tactic doesn't change with "Fullname".)

Comment: Thanks Mike, for some reason I missed this answer at the time but it is what I wanted. Andriy was correct with my meaning of bijective however I take your point that I should be very careful if there were to be new data added in future.